# Failed to parse names from next pages using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets

I've been trying to fetch the first provider name of a table from a [webpage](http://carf.org/advancedProviderSearch.aspx). As the data of that table spread across next pages, I have created a loop within the script to fetch the first provider name from all the next pages. I just can't figure out what exactly I'm doing wrong as `I'm always getting the first provider name of the table located in the first page, not from the next pages`.

If you wish to know how to populate result manually from that page:

1. Go to this site [website](http://carf.org/advancedProviderSearch.aspx)
2. Choose `US` from the dropdown right next to `Country`
3. Hit the `Search` button

I used the same logic in python and found success. However, the only thing differs from here is that I created session in python script and reused the same session in every loop.

This is how my current approach looks like:

```
function fetchInformation() {
  const url = 'http://carf.org/advancedProviderSearch.aspx';
  
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'headers': {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'

    },
  };
  
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
  var payload = {};
  payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = $('[id="__VIEWSTATE"]').first().attr('value'); 
  payload['EktronClientManager'] = $('[id="EktronClientManager"]').first().attr('value');
  payload['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = $('[id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]').first().attr('value'); 
  payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $('[id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]').first().attr('value'); 
  payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = '';
  payload['ctl00$usrWebsiteSearch$txtWebsiteSearch'] = 'Search CARF.org';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlCity'] = '0';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlZipcode'] = '0';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlCountry'] = 'US';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlProgram'] = '';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlProgramFocus'] = ''; 
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlPopulation'] = '';
  payload['ctl00$body$btnAdvSearch'] = 'Search';

  var i = 0;
  
  while (i<5){
      var options = {
        'method': 'POST',
        'payload': payload,
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'headers': {
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'

        },
      };

      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
      var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
      var elem = $('table#ctl00_body_gvProviderAdvSearch tr td > a').first().text();
      
      console.log(elem);
      
      var payload = {};
      payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = $('[id="__VIEWSTATE"]').first().attr('value'); 
      payload['EktronClientManager'] = $('[id="EktronClientManager"]').first().attr('value');
      payload['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = $('[id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]').first().attr('value'); 
      payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $('[id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]').first().attr('value'); 
      payload['ctl00$usrWebsiteSearch$txtWebsiteSearch'] = 'Search CARF.org';
      payload['ctl00$body$ddlCity'] = '0';
      payload['ctl00$body$ddlZipcode'] = '0';
      payload['ctl00$body$ddlCountry'] = 'US';
      payload['ctl00$body$ddlProgram'] = '';
      payload['ctl00$body$ddlProgramFocus'] = ''; 
      payload['ctl00$body$ddlPopulation'] = '';
      payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$body$gvProviderAdvSearch$ctl13$ctl01';
      i++;
  }

}
```

> How to grab the first provider name from a table of each page spread across next pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- When I saw your script, I thought that in your situation, the cookie might be required to be included.
- In the current stage, unfortunately, `User-Agent` cannot be changed with UrlFetchApp.

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function fetchInformation() {
  const url = 'http://carf.org/advancedProviderSearch.aspx';

  // Modified
  var options = {
    'method': 'GET',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
  var payload = {};
  payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = $('[id="__VIEWSTATE"]').first().attr('value');
  payload['EktronClientManager'] = $('[id="EktronClientManager"]').first().attr('value');
  payload['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = $('[id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]').first().attr('value');
  payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $('[id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]').first().attr('value');
  payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = '';
  payload['ctl00$usrWebsiteSearch$txtWebsiteSearch'] = 'Search CARF.org';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlCity'] = '0';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlZipcode'] = '0';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlCountry'] = 'US';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlProgram'] = '';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlProgramFocus'] = '';
  payload['ctl00$body$ddlPopulation'] = '';
  payload['ctl00$body$btnAdvSearch'] = 'Search';

  var cookie = response.getAllHeaders()["Set-Cookie"][1]; // Added

  var i = 0;

  while (i < 5) {
    var options = {
      'method': 'POST',
      'payload': payload,
      'muteHttpExceptions': true,
      'headers': { cookie }, // Modified
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var $ = Cheerio.load(response.getContentText());
    var elem = $('table#ctl00_body_gvProviderAdvSearch tr td > a').first().text();

    console.log(elem);

    var payload = {};
    payload['__VIEWSTATE'] = $('[id="__VIEWSTATE"]').first().attr('value');
    payload['EktronClientManager'] = $('[id="EktronClientManager"]').first().attr('value');
    payload['__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR'] = $('[id="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"]').first().attr('value');
    payload['__EVENTVALIDATION'] = $('[id="__EVENTVALIDATION"]').first().attr('value');
    payload['ctl00$usrWebsiteSearch$txtWebsiteSearch'] = 'Search CARF.org';
    payload['ctl00$body$ddlCity'] = '0';
    payload['ctl00$body$ddlZipcode'] = '0';
    payload['ctl00$body$ddlCountry'] = 'US';
    payload['ctl00$body$ddlProgram'] = '';
    payload['ctl00$body$ddlProgramFocus'] = '';
    payload['ctl00$body$ddlPopulation'] = '';
    payload['__EVENTTARGET'] = 'ctl00$body$gvProviderAdvSearch$ctl13$ctl01';
    i++;
  }

}
```

#### Result:

When the above-modified script is run, the following result can be seen in the log.

```
Greenleaf Job Training Services Inc
06Maren
10th District Substance Abuse Program dba New Beginnings, C.A.S.A.
12 Queen Street
12th Street House
```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Yeah, the script runs flawlessly now.

Comment: Hi Tanaike, I have one question on this. You used `'headers': { cookie }` instead of `'headers':  cookie ` within the script. As I'm new to apps script, I can't figure out what the curly brace `{}` is doing there.

Comment: @MITHU Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, `'headers': { cookie }` is the same with `'headers': { cookie: cookie }`. For example, you can see the document at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015). If this explanation was not useful, I apologize.